# Checkout onepage keeps redirecting to shopping-cart in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9, shopping-cart, checkout

Using Magento 1.9.1. in the website https://byroninbloom.com.au/ and After reaching the final step in Checkout, it loops/redirects back to the shopping cart. The articles in the shopping cart are not removed. I have been searching for days, and tried every possible solution I could find, like:

1) Increased Cookie Lifetime from 3600 to 86400

2) Redirect to CMS-page if cookies are disabled = No

3) web/url/redirect_to_base to 0 instead of 1

4) Clear var/cache and var/sessions folders

5) Disabled and changed shipping and payment methods

6) Increase memory limit to 256MB

and so on...
Here is the system log of another site that has the same issue.

2019-11-06T06:03:54+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Varien_Simplexml_Element::hasChildren(): Memory allocation failed  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Element.php on line 84
2019-11-11T06:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): (null)Entity: line 393: parser error : out of memory error  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2019-11-11T06:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>ship  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2019-11-11T06:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                      ^  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2019-11-11T06:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 393: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2019-11-11T06:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():             <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>ship  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
2019-11-11T06:05:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                                                                      ^  in /home/neoflamcom/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450

So you guy think it is due to out of memory limit?
I hope someone can help.

Comment: check log for errors, this might be due to some custom extension causing some issues. Try to disable those extensions and flush cache, then it should work

Comment: Yes I have tried to disabled those extensions but its still happening. When I tried to install the default magento to the current server in another site, and added a product to test the checkout page, it had the same issue. So do you think this issue comes from the server/apache?

Comment: did you check the logs? check all logs debug and exception, there you will find hints as to why that weird issue is happening

Comment: I have updated the system log in so you think it is due to out of memory limit?